# Can't RestSharp's AddJsonBody serialize a List of objects?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

For example:

```cs
var data = new List<object>()
{
    new {Name="a", Age=1},
    new {Name="a", Age=1},
};

var request = new RestRequest();
request.AddJsonBody(data);
```

There are no exceptions but the body remains null after calling `AddJsonBody`.

What's the correct way to do this? Or any workaround?

Do I have to serialize them into json string and post a string body?

RestSharp Version 106.15.0.0

Comment: You can try using Json.NET serializer instead of the default SimpleJson in 106

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the body first

```
var jsonInput = request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
```

then use `ParameterType.RequestBody` and provide the `application/json` content type.

```
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", jsonInput, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

---

Otherwise with your orignal code if you don't to explicitly serialize the body

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(data);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, still null body.

Comment: @Lee - Did you use `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;` with your orignal code and does that work? Then use `request.AddBody` not `AddJsonBody`

Comment: I might have misunderstood the `Body` property of `RestRequest` or something. I double-checked my server side code and it works just fine while the `Body` is always null. The body has been added anyway.